# add new element in laravel collection for friendship in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to display all users weather I send him friend request or not with friendship status for that. First of all I load all friend requests and received request in that manner.

```php
$users2 = User::with(['sentRequests' => function ($query) {
  ...
}])->with(['recievedRequests' => function ($query) {
  ...
}])->where('users.id', Auth::id())->get();
```

But then I also want to load other users so for that I create some query like that

```php
$sent = Friendship::where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->pluck('friend_id');

$received = Friendship::where('friend_id', Auth::id())
            ->pluck('user_id');
    
$users3 = User::whereNotIn('id', $sent)
            ->whereNotIn('id', $received)
            ->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())
            ->get();
```

Now I want to append $users3 to $users2 but when I done like that

```php
$users2->put('otherUsers',$users3);
```

It appended but not in the right manner , I want to append it in same manner as 'sentRequests' and 'recievedRequests' are.

Comment: `$users2->each(function (&$user) use ($users3) { $user->otherUsers = $users3; });` ?